# Change video quality through embed code on vimeo

Tags: php, vimeo-player

Can I change the video quality of vimeo video by send any parameter like youtube 
?hd=1 for on hd default.

PHP Code :

```
<a href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $key;?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;badge=0" >
```